# How to project data on a certain direction

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

For example, I have 2 data set, both of them are in 2-D.
Now the question is how to project these two data on a linear equation.

```
%%% Here is the data %%%
%%% The data are Gaussian distributed with means m1 and  m2, %%%
%%% and have a common covariance matrix C %%%
m1 = [0 3]'; %%% mean of data set 1
m2 = [3 2.5]';  %%% mean of data set 2
C1 = [2 1;1 2]; %%% covariance matrix %%%
C2 = [2 1;1 2]; %%% covariance matrix %%%
X1 = mvnrnd(m1,C1,N);
X2 = mvnrnd(m2,C2,N);
plot(X1(:,1),X1(:,2),'bx',X2(:,1),X2(:,2),'ro');
grid on
```

Comment: Do you want to project the simulated points to an arbitrary line, [like this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Orthogonal_Projection_Onto_a_Line)?

Comment: Yes, this result is enough for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution assuming that you want orthogonal projection to a line. Probably not the most efficient implementation, but at least the steps are easy to understand.

The line is defined by `a` and `b` parameters as:
    y = a*x + b;

```
N = 3;
%%% Here is the data %%%
%%% The data are Gaussian distributed with means m1 and  m2, %%%
%%% and have a common covariance matrix C %%%
m1 = [0 3]'; %%% mean of data set 1
m2 = [3 2.5]';  %%% mean of data set 2
C1 = [2 1;1 2]; %%% covariance matrix %%%
C2 = [2 1;1 2]; %%% covariance matrix %%%
X1 = mvnrnd(m1,C1,N);
X2 = mvnrnd(m2,C2,N);
figure
plot(X1(:,1),X1(:,2),'bx',X2(:,1),X2(:,2),'rx');
grid on
axis equal

% equation of the line
% y = a*x + b 
a = 1;
b = 1;

% normalized directional vector of the line
s = [a, a^2];
s = s./norm(s);

% translate points for easier work
X1(:,2) = X1(:,2)-b;
X2(:,2) = X2(:,2)-b;

% projection
X1p = (X1*s')*s;
X2p = (X2*s')*s;

% tranlate the points back
X1p(:,2) = X1p(:,2)+b;
X2p(:,2) = X2p(:,2)+b;

xx = -4:8;
hold on
plot(xx, a*xx+b, 'green')
plot(X1p(:,1),X1p(:,2),'bo',X2p(:,1),X2p(:,2),'ro')
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
title('Orthogonal projection')
```

`x` is the original point while `o` is its projection.
[image]